# Android unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface?

Tags: android, apk, android-security, google-developers-console, android-securityexception

I have publish my application on Google play developer console but application is suspended. I am getting following error and I haven't used HostnameVerifier interface in my code. I have just called Payment gateway of Paytm in Webview which used in website.

Error -
HostnameVerifier

Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: How to resolved that problem for publishing APK successfully ?

Comment: Presumably, if you're not using that interface _directly_, one of the components/libraries you are using (e.g. Paym) _is_ using it, and in an (apparently) unsafe way. I'd check you're using the latest versions of any such libraries, and either check the providers' websites or search the web for any issues with those libraries and the HostnameVerifier interface.